# Place spark TabBar on Bottom of ViewStacks (+ rounded corners pointing downwards)

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, tabbar

```
<s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" gap="0">
    <mx:ViewStack id="view" width="450" height="300" />
    <!-- NavigatorContent dynamically gets added to view on appComplete-->
    <s:TabBar dataProvider="{view}" skinClass="skins.CustomSparkTabBarSkin" />
</s:VGroup>
```

The Custom Skin:

```
<s:Skin 
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"     
alpha.disabled="0.5"><fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
    [HostComponent("spark.components.TabBar")]
    ]]>
</fx:Metadata> 

<fx:Script  fb:purpose="styling" >
    <![CDATA[ 

    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    /**  Push the cornerRadius style to the item renderers.*/
    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaleHeight:Number):void {
        const numElements:int = dataGroup.numElements;
        const cornerRadius:int = hostComponent.getStyle("cornerRadius");

        for (var i:int = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            var elt:UIComponent = dataGroup.getElementAt(i) as UIComponent;
            if (elt)
                elt.setStyle("cornerRadius", cornerRadius);
        }
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    }

    ]]>            
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>
<!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer#dataGroup -->
<s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Comes out to something like so: http://yozef.com/files/tabExample.png

I would like to place that TabBar at the Bottom of the viewstack, rounded corners pointing outwardly.

Comment: if I add rotation="180" to the TabBar
`<s:TabBar dataProvider="{view}" skinClass="skins.CustomSparkTabBarSkin" rotation="180"/>`
will make the matter all the more laughable.
I don't understand why is it so hard to create a TabNavigator with the buttons on the bottom?!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from scratch... While in Design mode...
Click the TabBar in the Outline view, in the properties view click the drop down next to Skin and choose Create Skin... Switch to source view and find the ButtonBarButton and add rotation="180" to it... (This is almost what you want but the text will be upside down) Go back to design view (on your TabBar custom skin) and click the ButtonBarButton in the Outline view and in the properties view click the drop down next to Skin and choose Create Skin... in the Outline view find the labelDisplay and add rotation="180"

this is the fastest way I can think of to achieve what you're looking for, you might find you want to tweak other values in the custom ButtonBarButton skin if the text isn't exactly where you'd like it...

Comment: That is a hack... and now I have both corners rounded... also, imagine the Index Navigator... The index is always wrong :S